# Is there a file container that can store GSM-EFR speech data?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, voip, gsm, file-format

Is there a file container that can store GSM-EFR speech data?
Just now I have such an file that contains a lot of RTP packages, the payload type of RTP package is GSM-EFR. I want to convert this file to a file that store the GSM-EFR data.
And then I need a audio player to decode the file and play the voice.
I have try the .amr file format,but encounter that .amr format can not distinguish the full rate and enhance full rate when they are both 12.2kbps.
I have try the ffmpeg, but this player can not decode GSM-EFR data.
So I need a file format and a audio player.Is there anyone can help me?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

GSM-EFR is same like AMR mode 7. Try packet your RTP payloads to AMR storage file with amr header mode 7. And be carefully, because in RTP payload can be signature 4 bit (0xC) in beginning, if have, you need delete at beginning 4 bit befor packing to AMR file